# How to retrieve output from Eggplant shell script command

Tags: shell, testing, eggplant

Trying to retrieve the output of my shell command, so I assign it to a variable and try to log it via the LogSuccess command.

```
put shell ("cat login.txt") into myOutput
LogSuccess myOutput
```

Unfortunately, I don't see anything in the logs or anyway to know that the command was actually sent to the shell.  Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current eggPlant API does not return the output of the `shell()` command.  A decent solution is to redirect the output of a command to a file, and read it immediately.

```
set destinationFile to "~/tempfile"
shell "cat login.txt > " & tempFile

LogSuccess file destinationFile
```

The above code sample will show you the output of the command.

Comment: where is that file located?  I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Tilde (~) is just an alias for your home directory on Unix (and Windows actually).  On windows I would look in C:\Users\<my username> and on linux/mac I would look in /home/<my username>.

Comment: You could also change that file path to be anything on your system. it could be `C:\tempfile` (for Windows) or `/tempfile` (for Linux/Mac) if either of those are more convenient.

Comment: Does it write it on the VNC or the actual computer your using?  I still can't find it on either.  Maybe I need to add a dot after the `/` in `~/tempfile`?

Comment: The dot did the trick.  I found the file on the system I am using.

Comment: Update: `shell()` now returns output except on Windows. This question appears to use a Bash shell, and could `put shell("cat login.txt") into output`, for example.